# Using doublequotes in bibtex fields and babel

Tags: punctuation, babel, biber, csquotes

I have autocreated (Mendeley - so editing by hand will be rendered useful on the next autocreation of the file) bib-files, which contain e.g. ".
Unfortunately, those " are treated as the LaTeX instruction to e.g. add an additional point to a following i.

What can I do to persuade LaTeX to "automask" them or something like this?
The problem itself seem to be related to babel - but shorthandoff doesn't solve my problem :-(.

test.tex:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman,english,german]{babel}  % deutschsprachig
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % utf8 encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Schriftkodierung
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, language=english]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lit.bib}

\begin{document}
I do cite\cite{Tsuzuki2012}.
\shorthandoff{"}
\printbibliography{}
\end{document}
```

lit.bib:

```
Automatically generated by Mendeley Desktop 1.10.3
Any changes to this file will be lost if it is regenerated by Mendeley.

BibTeX export options can be customized via Options -> BibTeX in Mendeley Desktop

@article{Tsuzuki2012,
annote = {in-depth discussion of the interactions},
author = {Tsuzuki, Seiji},
doi = {10.1039/c2pc90003c},
file = {:home/guntram/Dropbox/Uni/Literatur/Mendeley/pdf/Tsuzuki/Annual Reports Section C (Physical Chemistry)/Tsuzuki - 2012 - CH$\pi$ interactions.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0260-1826},
journal = {Annual Reports Section "C" (Physical Chemistry)},
keywords = {CH-pi,Methyl,Phenyl,bonding theory,hbb,review,theory,weak interactions},
language = {en},
mendeley-tags = {CH-pi,Methyl,Phenyl,bonding theory,hbb,review,theory,weak interactions},
month = may,
number = {1},
pages = {69},
publisher = {The Royal Society of Chemistry},
title = {{CH/$\pi$ \" interactions}},
url = {http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/2012/pc/c2pc90003c},
volume = {108},
year = {2012}
}
```

The problem are the " in the title and the journal name which don't appear as such.

pdflatex doesn't complain, biber yields:

biber test

```
INFO - This is Biber 1.8
INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'lit.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'lit.bib'
WARN - BibTeX subsystem: /tmp/zhImWwyF7r/lit.bib_7291.utf8, line 6, warning: 172 characters of junk seen at toplevel
INFO - Overriding locale 'de_DE.UTF-8' default tailoring 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting 'entry' list 'nty' keys
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de_DE.UTF-8'
INFO - Writing 'test.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to test.bbl
INFO - WARNINGS: 1
```

Anybody any idea on how I can change this behaviour on the LaTeX side?

Comment: Mhhh, the ` \" ` in the title seems just wrong to me, the website indicated by the URL does not contain any character that would warrant a `\"`, so the exported title seems wrong. But there is another weird thing I noticed, `\usepackage[ngerman,english,german]{babel}` does not seem to work to well, but `\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}` and `\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}` both do the expected thing. So there might be a problem with `biblatex` and `babel`'s `german`. (It is certainly not a biber problem, as the `.bbl` file is fine.)

Comment: Yepp! Thanks for the comment! Changing the order to [german, english, ngerman] works (I do need the german package itself, too)!
The " was added by myself to check, wether the problem was related to wether it is located in the title or other fields...
To wrap up: ngerman does handle the " in an acceptable (right?) way :-) !

Thanks!

Comment: @moewe Make that an answer, please.

Comment: @lockstep Done. Feel free to edit, because I have no idea what caused this mayhem with `german` and why it works flawlessly with `ngerman`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`babel` takes the last language passed to it via the options to be the document's main language. In your case, the document's main language was `german` (that is German with old rule orthography).

It seems though `biblatex` did not play together with `german` particularly well, while together with `ngerman` everything works fine.

So you could load

```
\usepackage[german,english,ngerman]{babel}
```

which makes `ngerman` the main language (it is advisable anyway if you write something now to stick to new rules, but it is also a matter of personal taste, I suppose).

The problem is not related to biber, as the `.bbl` file has the expected content (at least when I ran your example on my computer).